# Eloquent eager loading not working with nested fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get User model with relations and nested fields. This first try is working fine:

```
$user = \App\User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->with(['userdoc'])->get();
```

Its returning the entire userdoc object. But I want only two fields, so I'm trying:

```
$user = \App\User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->with(['userdoc:id,number'])->get();
```

And this way it's returning `userdoc:null` in `toArray()` JSON.

This seems to be ok according to with documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

I'm on Laravel 5.6.

Adding some more information:

Without specific fields gets the entire object

```
$user = \App\User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->with('userdoc')->get();
return response()->json($user->toArray(), 200);

[
    {
        "id": 11,
        "email": "xxxxx",
        "slug": "xxxxx",
        "created_at": "xxxxx",
        "updated_at": "xxxxx",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "first_name": "xxxxx",
        "last_name": "xxxxx",
        "is_verified": 0,
        "userdoc": {
            "id": 11,
            "created_at": "2018-08-20 13:20:29",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-20 13:20:29",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "user_id": 11,
            "type": "document",
            "number": "xxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
]
```

Determining `userdoc` fields makes the object becomes as null

```
$user = \App\User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->with('userdoc:id,number')->get();
return response()->json($user->toArray(), 200);

[
    {
        "id": 11,
        "email": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "slug": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "created_at": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "updated_at": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "first_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "last_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "is_verified": 0,
        "userdoc": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You result is because you does not select related primary key `user_id`. Try this

```
$user = \App\User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->with(['userdoc:id,user_id,number'])->get();
```

Comment: can you add `userdoc` table structure??

Comment: added example in question

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the brackets `[]` in :

```
$user = \App\User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->with(['userdoc:id,number'])->get();
_________________________________________________________^___________________^
```

Should be :

```
$user = \App\User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->with('userdoc:id,number')->get();
```

You should pass the foreign key too in the `with` passed fields :

```
...->with('userdoc:id, user_id, number')
```

Comment: it returns the same :(

Comment: Show us the result please

Comment: added results in question

Comment: the `with` method accepts an array of relationships. Having those squared brackets there will work just fine (even if not needed in this particular scenario).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that your `userdocs` table has a `user_id` property and you are using a one-to-many relationship between `users` and `userdocs`. If that is the case, you also need to fetch the foreign key from `userdoc`:

`$user = \App\User::where('id', auth()->id())->with(['userdoc:id,number,user_id'])->get();`

Answer (score 1):

I had to add id to my nested eager loading to get the name of my client:

```
$foo = Visitor_visit::with('client:id,name')->get();
```

otherwise it was null, hope that helps someone.